# Interfaces and multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, com, polymorphism

I want to design my code somehow like Microsoft's COM, meaning:

- I have my dll with different objects implementing different interfaces,
- I only expose the interfaces to the client (this part is not really an issue here but it's just to give more context).

Now as an example, taking this code (you can run it here https://onlinegdb.com/Z7RPQVrCZ):

```
class IParent
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const = 0;  
};

class IChild : public IParent
{
public:
    virtual void bar() const = 0;  
};

class Parent : public IParent
{
private:
        int a_;
        
public:
    virtual void foo() const override { /* for ex: do something with a_ */ }
};

class Child : public IChild, public Parent
{
public:
    virtual void bar() const override {}
    
    // My issue is here:
    using Parent::foo;
};

int main()
{
    Child c;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the compile error:

`main.cpp:38:11: error: cannot declare variable ‘c’ to be of abstract type ‘Child’`

Although if I replace `using Parent::foo;` by:

`virtual void foo() const override { return Parent::foo(); }`

It compiles normally. But what is the point since **I don't want to override it**. In some way I would even want to make `Parent::foo` `final` for example.

I imagine the issue is that `Child` inherits from `IChild` and `Parent` and that both inherit from `IParent`. But then:

- Why the expicit `using` doesn't work?
- And if it is what it is, does this mean this design just doesn't
  match my needs here?
- Or do I just implement it badly?

Comment: Child should do this: `void foo() const override { Parent::foo(); }`  Or use `virtual public` inheritance.

Comment: One way is to use the _Mixin Pattern_ (more ore less what COM implementations like ATL do).

Comment: Why derive IChild from IParent at all? It are different aspects of a person so it is fine to adress them independently.  It makes more sense if you also will add professions or other aspects to a Person. Also have a look at crtp/mixin classes to create classes that implement those different aspects.  using inheritance for code reuse might look like a good idea because it is "less" code but is unmaintainable in the end.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I think OP meant parent/child more in sense of technical terms than persons.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Could be :)  But still when multiple inheritance is involved mixin is the way to go. I don't know who said it but I live by : "Whatever you think (class) inheritance is rarely the solution",  but do use "interfaces" (abstract baseclasses)

Comment: The COM principle is quite simple: Query for interface (type safely), dispatch and use it.

Comment: In C++ that (QueryInterface) would be a dynamic cast to an abstract baseclass (interface).

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes `dynamic_cast` is a wonderful utility. But COM was designed to be language agnostic and couldn't use it. I've always been impressed by the base COM design, simple and elegant and very flexible.

Comment: I was just pointing out C++ without COM.  The basics of COM are elegant, but I disagree COM  is always simple and elegant in practise. When you go beyond oleautomation its a pain and the whole STA model is a disaster. (I know, I've been doing COM for almost 25 years now, so right from the first version).  But this is way outside the scope of the question so I digress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went with *@Pepijn Kramer* answer. But it has some typo so I rewrite it wrt to my example case:

```
class IParent
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const = 0;  
};

class IChild : public IParent
{
public:
    virtual void bar() const = 0;  
};

template<typename T>
class Parent : public T
{
private:
        int a_;
        
public:
    virtual void foo() const override { /* for ex: do something with a_ */ }
};

class Child : public Parent<IChild>
{
public:
    virtual void bar() const override {}
};

int main()
{
    Child c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Example of (crtp) mixin using inheritance to avoid diamonds.
In this way inheritance is used to aggregate functionality in a class with multiple "base" behaviors.

```
#include <iostream>

class foo_itf
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class bar_itf
{
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

// do NOT put reusable code in a baseclass
// but in a mixin class
template<typename class_t>
class foo_impl :
    public foo_itf
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        std::cout << "foo\n";
    }
};

template<typename class_t>
class bar_impl :
    public bar_itf
{
public:
    void bar() override
    {
        std::cout << "bar\n";
    }
};

// "left diamond" class replacement
class foo_t :
    public foo_impl<foo_t>
{
};

// "right diamond" class replacement
class bar_t :
    public bar_impl<bar_t>
{
};

// class that can do both
// but is NOT derived from a common single parent class
// so there is no diamond.
class foo_bar_t :
    public foo_impl<foo_bar_t>,
    public bar_impl<foo_bar_t>
{
};


int main()
{
    foo_t foo;
    bar_t bar;
    foo_bar_t foobar;

    foo.foo();
    bar.bar();

    foobar.foo();
    foobar.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. :) did not understand template<typename class_t> was used.

Comment: Thanks but I don't really get this example. Like in

`template<typename class_t> class foo_impl : public foo_itf`

What's the point of the template here since `class_t` type doesn't appear anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Adding virtual actually works.

```
class IParent
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const = 0;  
};

class IChild : virtual public IParent
{
public:
    virtual void bar() const = 0;  
};

class Parent : virtual public IParent
{
private:
        int a_;
        
public:
    virtual void foo() const override { /* for ex: do something with a_ */ }
};

class Child : public IChild, public Parent
{
public:
    virtual void bar() const override {}
    
    //My issue is here:
    
    // This raise compile error "Child is abstract"
    using Parent::foo;
    
    // This works, but I don't like it much...
    // virtual void foo() const override { return Parent::foo(); }
};

int main()
{
    Child c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Important fact about software : that it seems to work doesn't mean it is correct or good design.

Comment: @PepijnKramer is using virtual during inheritance is a bad practice?

Comment: I mean Diamond inheritance should still be avoided. Mostly it is used to do code reuse... there are better ways (I'll add an example).